# c++ Dynamic array using strings won't accept strings

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to put the strings in a temporary array into a dynamic array. But the compiler just breaks when it hits that.

where dynaicArray is called:

```
string* dynamicArray = NULL;
```

Here is where it is breaking:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= (size); i++)
{
dynamicArray[i] = tempArray[i];
}
```

Where tempArray is filled:

```
void populateArray(int& size, string*& dynamicArray)
{
char decide;
string tempArray[100]; //Holds the strings until the size is known
bool moreStrings = true;
while (moreStrings == true)
{
    cout << "\nEnter your string here:";
    cin >> tempArray[size];
    cout << "\nDo you want to enter another string? Y/N:";
    cin >> decide;
    decide = toupper(decide);
    size ++;
    dynamicArray = new string[size];
    if (decide == 'N')
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= (size); i++) //moves all of the strings from tempArray to dynamicArray
        {
            string temp;
            temp = tempArray[i];
            dynamicArray[i] = temp;
        }
        moreStrings = false;
    }
}
}
```

PS: I know vectors are better. Unfortunately they're not an option.

Comment: Whenever I hear the words "dynamic array" in C++ I always think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Maybe you should too?

Comment: Why not just use a vector?

Comment: what do you mean by "the compiler breaks"? please show the error

Comment: If you'd use a std::vector<string> in stead of a dynamic array, you wouldn't need the temporary array either, making your code much more robust (what if the user enters more than 100 strings?)

Comment: `string tempArray[100];` and `while (moreStrings == true)` - hmm...

Comment: Famous last words: "if I just take <N>, then that will always be enough" :)  Should be lesson nr. 1 in programming courses...

Comment: why not vector<string>?

Comment: Where do you initialize `size`in `populateArray`?

Comment: Also, you are not checking that `size` not will become greater or equals than 100, the size of `tempArray`.

Comment: @Narkha: it's passed as an arg-by-reference, hopefully initialized before the call

Comment: Only as an advice about good programing practices, inicialize it to 0 in the function, or at lest check it. What if the value passed is negative or 1000000?

Answer (score 1):

Some design ideas:

- the code in the `if (decide == 'N')` block is better placed after the while, to make the while smaller == more readable
- once the above is implemented, you can set the `moreStrings` var directly with the result of your `decide == 'N'`; no need for an explicit `if` there anymore
- you now do a `dynamicArray = new string[size];` in each pass through the while, which is an enormous memory leak (you'r overwriting the newly created dynamic array with a new copy without reclaiming the old one out first - see dalete[])
- as already mentioned: don't assume 100 will be enough - read "Buffer overflow" (only viable solution: make it a dynamic array as well and re-allocate it to a bigger one if it gets full)
- better initialize `size` in the function before you use it - much safer; callers don't need to remember to do it themselves
- C++ arrays are 0-based, so when you start copying them you'd also better start at 0 and not at 1
- nitpick: `for (int i = 1; i <= (size); i++)`: the () around size are superfluous
- bonus advanced nitpick: use `++size` and `++i` in these contexts; it's a bit more efficient
- you now use the var `tmp` to copy from the temp array to the dynamic one and the code is also somewhat structured to suggest you're using it to swap the strings between the two arrays (you're not) - rename the tmp variable or get rid of it altogether

Comment: Nitpick to nitpick `for (int i = 1; i <= (size); i++)` has much bigger problem than superfluous parenthesis - it should be `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: Yeah, I already addressed that, though it's buried somewhat in there between the rest ;)